# Copy file to Local folder in Win 8

Tags: c#, file, windows-8, microsoft-metro, copy

i want file copy from pictures libary to local folder:

```
string path = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\files";//error:Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
folder = await folder.GetFolderAsync(path);
 await file.CopyAsync(folder);
```

And i got this error:Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetFolderAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfolderasync) gets a single sub-folder from the current folder using the specified folder name. In your code, your `folder must be null`, you need to initialize it to some value. This should work for you -

```
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
folder = await folder.GetFolderAsync("files");
await file.CopyAsync(folder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `ApplicationData` is `null`
or `.Current` is `null`
or `.LocalFolder` is `null` 
or `.Path` is `null`.

You will need to find out which one and correct it.

Comment: It's impossible to check those values in Explorer. Use a debugger. If you are using Visual Studio, press F5 and if it breaks at the exception, mouseover the parts that I mentioned. One of them is null.